# Telegram group ban/boot/kick user

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to create a Telegram bot to moderate a group and be able to ban/boot/kick users from the group.

I could not find anything in the Telegram API to boot a user from a group, how can a bot do this through the API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [banChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#banchatmember) to remove a user from a group.

> The bot must be an administrator in the chat for this to work and must have the appropriate admin rights.

Comment: Looks like this method does not remove user from group and user is still visible in members list.

Comment: After almost two hours of trying to figure out what's going on I removed bot from group and added it again. And now it works. I'm so angry right now.

Comment: try this https://adby.io/add-telegram-bots-to-groups/#:~:text=Follow%20these%20steps%3A%20Open%20the%20group%20and%20tap,and%20hold%20to%20see%20Remove%20from%20group%20option

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, the API call just get's ignored. The bot has sufficient privileges. The method returns `True`. Do you know what fixed it for you? Also using `banChatMember` has no effect.

Comment: link is broken!

Answer (score 2):

To remove a user without banning them, use [`unbanChatMember`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#unbanchatmember).

> this method guarantees that after the call the user is not a member of the chat, but will be able to join it. So if the user is a member of the chat they will also be removed from the chat.

Comment: from documentation it seems that this method is to be used on a previously banned user.