# Telegram Bot remove members

Tags: bots, telegram, member

Somebody has any idea how to remove members in a group by using Telegram Bot? I want to do a list with the members who will be in a group, so if someone adds another member, I'd like the Bot will be able to know if that person isn't in the list and this way remove from the group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telegram group ban/boot/kick user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817082/telegram-group-ban-boot-kick-user)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop members from adding users you do not know simply just close the `Add Users` option in the management panel of the group and no need to remove them after joining to the group.